# Using fuerte with python 3

Tags: ros, python, python3, rospy, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen that several issues regarding python 3 support have been solved recently, e.g. [1]. However, I could not find any information how to actually use the new release with python 3? That means how do I get the python libraries compiled and installed in a python3-compatible pythonpath etc.?

[1] https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3166

Ok, trying michikarg's suggestion I end up in this error:

```
>>> import roslib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/vol/corcse/ros-fuerte/x86_64/src/ros-underlay/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from roslib.launcher import load_manifest
  File "/vol/corcse/ros-fuerte/x86_64/src/ros-underlay/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>
    import rospkg
ImportError: No module named rospkg

jwienke@augit:/vol/corcse/ros-fuerte/x86_64/src/PyYAML-3.10$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/vol/corcse/ros-fuerte/x86_64/lib/python3.1/site-packages:/vol/corcse/ros-fuerte/x86_64/src/ros-underlay/ros/core/roslib/src/
```

With the patch mentioned below I am now able to use roslib. However rospy and std_msgs do not work:

```
jwienke@augit:/vol/corcse/ros-fuerte/x86_64/src/ros-underlay/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib$ python3
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79147, Dec  9 2011, 20:47:34) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rospy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/vol/corcse/ros-fuerte/x86_64/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ros_comm-1.8.7-py2.6.egg/rospy/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from std_msgs.msg import Header
  File "/vol/corcse/ros-fuerte/x86_64/lib/python2.6/site-packages/std_msgs/msg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _Bool import *
ImportError: No module named _Bool
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32536/using-fuerte-with-python-3/) by [languitar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2243/languitar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After playing around a bit with ROS and Python3, i basically got ROS messaging running from python2 and 3! A created a ticket and patches, so feel free to test:

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3949

I also had to fix genpy. You can download the lated trunk (already including my patch the fixes your problem with the _Bool import) from github:

https://github.com/ros/genpy

Cheers

Michi

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a patch for  `/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/stacks.py` that allows you to import roslib using Python3. Let me know if this worked for you:

[http://ias.cs.tum.edu/~kargm/stacks_py3k.patch](http://ias.cs.tum.edu/%7Ekargm/stacks_py3k.patch)

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To limit confusion for those reading this page, @michikarg and @languitar are discussing useful work for future python3 migration, done in branches of various core ROS components.

*ROS Fuerte **does not** officially support python3.*

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-04-25**:
Thanks, i should have pointed that out at the beginning of my answer.